# How to bind "Apply to Folders" to a hotkey?

Tags: windows-10

I am wondering how I can bind this to a hotkey?

[image]

Comment: You can't. You can navigate that dialog with tab. So you might be able to use some key automation software for it (e.g. AutoIt or AHK). The question would probably why you'd want to. There might be a better way to do it.

Comment: Is there a larger goal? **Apply to Folders** sets a custom folder template --- not something you normally change frequently.